# How do I prevent a button from being clicked until a separate button on the same page has been clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a page where a video must be watched before starting a game. The video and game link are on the same page. Is there a simple way to "lock" a link until a separate link has been clicked. 
Here is a snippet of the buttons:

```html
<table class="t1">
        <tr>
            <th class="th1"><a href="<?php echo $video_url;?>" target="_blank"><div type = "button" class="button button1">Watch Video</div></a></th>
            <th class="th1"><a><div class="button button2">Objective:<div class ="desc"><?php echo $game_description;?></div></div></a></th>
            <th class="th1"><a href="<?php echo $construct_url;?>" target="_blank"><div type = "button" class="button button3">Play Game</div></a></th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any buttons there

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm guessing the links are his "buttons"

Comment: @j08691 Are you sure it's not the **div** `type=button`? :)

Comment: Your PHP has nothing to do with the actual question so I removed the tag. Post the rendered HTML and the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: @AlonEitan Nope. But without the link, the div with the class button is just a div. :/

Comment: Please specify *exactly* the functionality that you desire. Which button must be clicked first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have buttons, but anchors, so you can prevent the default action on one anchor, until the other has been clicked, like so

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
var skip = true;

btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  skip = false;
});

btn2.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (skip) evt.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<table class="t1">
  <tr>
    <th class="th1">
      <a href="test" target="_blank" id="btn1">
        <div type="button" class="button button1">Watch Video</div>
      </a>
    </th>
    <th class="th1">
      <a>
        <div class="button button2">Objective:
          <div class="desc">
            description
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </th>
    <th class="th1">
      <a href="test" target="_blank" id="btn2">
        <div type="button" class="button button3">Play Game</div>
      </a>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your deliver both, video and game, to the client there is nothing preventing the client from just deleting the restrictions from the DOM.

Assuming a regular user, you may use the `disabled` attribute to prevent somebody from clicking a button. A more secure method would be, to not deliver a link at all, requesting and adding it **after** the video has been watched by the user (maybe add the button but specify the `href` attribute only, if the video has been watched).

This obviously has to be done using JavaScript. There are several solutions involving either not delivering the link, hiding it or using the HTML5 `disabled` attribute to prevent a button from being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use JQUERY for this, you could just not display the link until button is clicked for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showThisSecond").hide();
    $("#showThisFirst").click(function(){
       $("$showThisSecond").show();
    });
});

<button id='showThisFirst' />
<button id='showThisSecond' />
```